# lowering width % allows centering a form?

Tags: html, css, forms

totally weird and I couldn't fix it so that it was centered...finally I played around with different width % and came to the conclusion that decreasing the % allowed it to center....but it seems backwards....can someone just explain why its doing this....i mean I got it to work but I don't want to burn that technique in my brain if its only a coincedence or something....please explain

HTML CODE

```
 <form action="mailto:info@saucysbulldogs.com" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="fName" maxlength="20" size="30" placeholder="First Name" required="required" autocomplete="on"><br />
            <input type="text" id="lName" maxlength="20" size="30" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" autocomplete="on"><br />
            <input type="email" id="email" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Email" required="required" autocomplete="on"><br />
            <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="30" maxlength="100" wrap="hard" placeholder="Message..." required="required" /></textarea></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear" />
           </form>
</body>     
</html>
```

Here is the css code for the form....I tried 100% and it didn't work...then finally had to get down to 25% in order to center it....you can see it at www.saucysbulldogs.com

```
form {
padding:10px;
width:25%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;  
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That you can't center an element with a width of 100% should be pretty clear for you.
When you keep the percentage lower and the margin at 0 auto it get's centered.

But there is no need to go down to 25%.

When I look to your url I see no problem. Your form there has a width of 85% and is centered in its parent container.